# Volume generated by a solid revolution

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

Find the volume of solid generated by region in the first quadrant bounded by curve $y=x^2$, below by the x axis and on the right by the line $x=2$ and about the line $x=-3$

How to set up integral in this question?

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, shift the curve right such that the axis of revolution becomes the $y$ axis:

$$y = (x - 3)^2$$

Now put $x$ in terms of $y$ so that we can integrate along $y$:

$$x = \sqrt{y} + 3$$

Then, calculate the volume of the solid formed by revolving the region bounded on top by $y = 4$, below by the $x$ axis, on the left by the $y$ axis and about the $y$ axis:

$$R' = \pi \int_0^4 (\sqrt{y} + 3)^2 dy$$

Afterwards, subtract this volume off that of the cylinder formed by revolving the region bounded on top by $y = 4$, on the left by the $y$ axis, on the right by $x = 5$ and about the $y$ axis to get the required volume:

$$R = \pi\cdot(2 + 3)^2\cdot4 - R'$$

Comment: I don't understand it. Why have you shifted towards right when our axis of revolution is $x=-3$ ?

Comment: @Mathematics Because the equation for the volume of revolution as you know works only if you are rotating the region about the axes. By shifting the region right, we force the axis of revolution to shift to become the axis.

Comment: As per disk method, shouldn't it be $dx$  in $R'$ as axis of rotation is horizontal?

Comment: And why is method followed in Sky's answer incorrect?

Comment: The integral was taken along the vertical axis, so it should be $dy$ instead. Sky's method works as well - my answer simply presents a more elementary approach that requires only some algebra, graph transformation and calculus to derive.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easiest to use the [Shell method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration), so we find the radius and height of the "shells." The radius (distance from axis of revolution to inside of shell) you can see is $3+x$ and the height is just the $y$ value ($=x^2$) so the volume is $$2\pi\int_0^2 x^2 (3+x)\text{d}x=24\pi$$